# SQL View Not Joining

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with ZipCodes in them and they are the same in each table.  The column datatypes are the same and the same size as well.  Does anyone know why my view isn't being updated correct?  It always shows NULL For the second table.  Thanks

```
USE [DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[myview]
AS
SELECT     dbo.Table1.Division, dbo.Table1.RegionName AS Region, dbo.Table1.AccountDir AS RegionManager, dbo.Table2.key, 
                      dbo.Table2.ZipCode, dbo.Table3.ZipCity, dbo.Table3.ZipCounty, dbo.Table3.ZipState
FROM         dbo.Table2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Table1 ON dbo.Table2.key = dbo.Table1.key LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Table3 ON dbo.Table2.ZipCode = dbo.Table3.ZipCode
```

ZipCodes are just like this 05412.  Normal 5 digit zips.

Comment: Can you provide the code?  Right now it would just be guesses.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `zipcode` field?  Can you post some sample data for those fields? Are you certain that the zip code exists in both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a formatting issue with the csv being uploaded with the bulk load command...  I imported it into an access db and then imported it into my sql db with no issues.  0dd

Answer (score 2):

I would have to see your data to give a solid answer, but I suspect there are no records in table2 that meet the condition:

```
dbo.Table2.key = dbo.Table1.key
```

Since you are doing a left join on this condition, null values will be returned for every record in Table1 that does not have a matching record in table2.

Take a look at this article to get a better understanding of how the different types of joins work:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 2):

I am going to suggest a few things, if the datatype on the `ZipCode` field is a `varchar` then you might have an issue with whitespace, so you can try to trim the value to remove any whitespace.  If there is whitespace, then you could not be matching the records:

```
SELECT dbo.Table1.Division, 
    dbo.Table1.RegionName AS Region, 
    dbo.Table1.AccountDir AS RegionManager, 
    dbo.Table2.key, 
    dbo.Table2.ZipCode, 
    dbo.Table3.ZipCity, 
    dbo.Table3.ZipCounty, 
    dbo.Table3.ZipState
FROM  dbo.Table2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table1 
    ON dbo.Table2.key = dbo.Table1.key 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table3 
    ON LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.Table2.ZipCode)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.Table3.ZipCode))
```

But you need to be sure that your data exists in all of the tables. Otherwise you will get no results.

Comment: How Can I see the specifics about the data in each cell?  I have the tables populated but for some reason the ZIPCODES are not joining

Comment: Do a select on `Table2` and a separate one on `Table3` to see if there is data in the `zipcode` fields.

Comment: Its there and I just can't figure out why its not joining up.

Comment: @Intelwalk can you edit your original question and post some sample data for each table?  or even better create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the data